# Monitor at first shows "overclocking" when starting KDE

Tags: xorg, kde, graphics, monitors

When I boot my Manjaro Linux system, I get a graphical GRUB, then some boot text messages and finally when KDE Plasma starts, my monitor only shows the message "Overclocking" and nothing else. This can be fixed if I just reconnect the monitor, but next time I boot I get the same issue again. I have not modified any particular configuration on my system.

Where can I look to investigate if there is some kind of issue with some indication how to fix it? Any idea how to fix this?

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070] vendor: eVga.com. driver: nvidia
    v: 530.41.03 alternate: nouveau,nvidia_drm non-free: 530.xx+
    status: current (as of 2023-05) arch: Pascal code: GP10x
    process: TSMC 16nm built: 2016-21 pcie: gen: 1 speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 16
    link-max: gen: 3 speed: 8 GT/s bus-ID: 0a:00.0 chip-ID: 10de:1b81
    class-ID: 0300
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 21.1.8 compositor: kwin_x11 driver: X:
    loaded: nvidia gpu: nvidia display-ID: :0 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 3440x1440 s-dpi: 109 s-size: 802x333mm (31.57x13.11")
    s-diag: 868mm (34.19")
  Monitor-1: HDMI-0 res: 3440x1440 hz: 100 dpi: 110
    size: 797x334mm (31.38x13.15") diag: 864mm (34.02") modes: N/A
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 530.41.03 renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GTX
    1070/PCIe/SSE2 direct-render: Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be gone, but not sure if  an update to `nvidia 535.54.03` or kernel `6.4.2` made the difference.